# Spyder SymPy Wont Print Symbolic Math

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, spyder

I setup Anaconda 2.0.0 (Win 64).
It has SymPy 0.7.5.

I configured Spyder (2.3.0rc that came with Anaconda) to use symbolic math:

*Tools > Preferences > iPython console > Advanced Settings > Symbolic Mathematics*

I create a new project and a new file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

x = Symbol('x')
integrate(x, x)

print("Completed.")
```

When I run this (Python or iPython console) it does not print the integral -- it only prints *Completed.*

But what is weird is that while in the console that just did the run if I then re-type:

```
integrate(x, x)
```

It does print the integral.

So running from a file never prints any symbolic math but typing in the console manually does?

Can anyone help with this issue -- maybe it some sort of configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly do you run the file in IPython? Using `%run`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Running a script is not the same as executing code in IPython. When you run the code in a cell or prompt in IPython, it captures the output of the last command and displays it to you. When you run a script, the script is just run, and the only thing that is displayed is what is printed to the screen.

I don't think there is a way to send the IPython display object (which would be needed to get pretty latex output) from a script, but I may be misunderstanding how spyder executes the code in IPython, or missing some hooks that it has. You can try

```
from IPython.display import display
display(integrate(x, x))
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot that `IPython.display` is the module, not the function.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `integrate` doesn't print automatically, it just returns the output. You will have to pass it to `print` function to get the output. Try using following code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
x = Symbol('x')
print(integrate(x, x))
print("Completed.")
```

In Python console(or IPython console) returned statements are automatically printed.

**Update:** Use `pprint` for a nice formatted output.

Comment: When I use print I get regular text printing in Spyder's iPython console. If I type in the console: integrate(x,x) then I get nice rich text. Can I force my code to output nice rich text when it runs too?

Comment: It's odd that it works without print in an iPython Web Notebook. If I could get Spyder iPython console to behave like a web notebook that would be great! (actually in web notebook it does not work if I have a print statement like print("Completed') but it does work if there are no competing print statements!

Comment: Yeah you can do so. You'll have to use `pprint` for that. Import it from `sympy.printing`.

Comment: pprint does do some formatting but still only with basic text -- it still does not give the nice rich text that you get if you type the calls manually into the iPython console. So if I run with pprint I get a text output and then if I go to that console and type integrate(x,x) I then get the nice rich text.